# Why isnt my anchor tags not showing style on hover?

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

These are the styles I am trying to apply on the li elements when I hover over the list items. But these styles don't appear as of now. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#menu-ul a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#menu-ul a:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-ul">
          <span class="menu-item-selection">
            <a href="#" id="brunch"><li>Brunch</li></a>
          </span>
          <span class="menu-item-selection">
            <a href="#" id="bowls"><li>Bowls</li></a>
          </span>
          <span class="menu-item-selection">
            <a href="#" id="beverages"> <li>Beverages</li></a>
          </span>
          <span class="menu-item-selection">
            <a href="#" id="salads"> <li>Salads</li></a>
          </span>
          <span class="menu-item-selection">
            <a href="#" id="desserts"> <li>Desserts</li></a>
          </span>
        </ul>
```

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid.** `ul` can only have `li` children, and `li` can only have `ul` or `ol` parent.

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all fix your structure: `<span>` can't be a child of `<ul>` element.
This should look like this:

```
<ul id="menu-ul">
  <li class="menu-item-selection"> 
    <a href="#" id="brunch">Brunch</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-selection"> 
    <a href="#" id="bowls">Bowls</a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should target the li element, and not the a element:

```
#menu-ul a:hover li{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#menu-ul a:focus li{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with just targetting to `li` after `a:hover` but I would change html structure

```css
#menu-ul a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#menu-ul a:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <ul id="menu-ul">
          <li>
            <span class="menu-item-selection">
              <a href="#" id="brunch">Brunch</a>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li>
          <span class="menu-item-selection">
            <a href="#" id="bowls">Bowls</a>
          </span>
          </li>
          <li>
          <span class="menu-item-selection">
            <a href="#" id="beverages">Beverages</a>
          </span>
          </li>
</ul>
```